# How to fix AttributeError with ImageTk and Tkinter in python3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is my code that I had written, I had fixed previous errors with help from other users. However this one stumps me. This is my code

I placed comment markers around the area I believe is the issue. To fix this problem I had read through a few sources however, it hasn't turned up any results.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import time
from PIL import ImageTk, Image



tot_time=0
del_time=0
imgpath=r'logo.jpg'

def NewTab():
    start=timer()
    time.sleep(del_time) #user defined delay time
    window.withdraw()
    win2.deiconify()
    end=timer()
    tot_time=end-start

    labW2.configure(text=('That took %s miliseconds or %s seconds'%(str(round(tot_time*1000,5)),str(round(tot_time,5)))))

def close():
    sys.exit()

def NTButt():
    win2.withdraw()
    window.deiconify()


win2=tk.Tk()
win2.geometry('1100x900')
win2.title('Button Click')
labW2=tk.Label(win2, text='ERROR: Time could not be calculated')
butW2=tk.Button(win2, text='Go back', bg='White', command=NTButt)
btn2W2=tk.Button(win2, text='Leave', bg='Red', command=close)
labW2.pack()
butW2.pack()
btn2W2.pack()
win2.withdraw()



window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry('1100x900')
window.title('Hello World')
lab1= tk.Label(window, text='Input the desired delay time')
ent=tk.Entry(window)
btn=tk.Button(window, text='Go to new window', bg='Blue', command=NewTab)
btn2=tk.Button(window, text='Leave', bg='Red', command=close)
###############################################
imgset=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgpath))
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgset) 
labimg = tk.Label(window, image=photo)
labimg.image = photo 
labimg.pack()
###############################################
lab1.pack()
ent.pack()
btn.pack()
btn2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Ill include the error message I received

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonScripts\trunk\Personal\PythonWindow_ForTiming.py", line 53, in <module>
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgset) 
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 106, in __init__
    mode = Image.getmodebase(mode)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 290, in getmodebase
    return ImageMode.getmode(mode).basemode
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageMode.py", line 50, in getmode
    return _modes[mode]
KeyError: <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x0000000002A06208>
Exception ignored in: <bound method PhotoImage.__del__ of <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x0000000002DC45C0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 116, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

I am new to tkinter and this may just be a error on my part, please comment solution to help me understand. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no TKinter expert, but it seems that the line which is raising the exception: 
`photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgset)` Is not needed; You've already loaded the image in the previous line.

The exception is raised because you are passing in an instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` to `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`

So, the bit of code in question becomes:

```
###############################################
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgpath))
labimg = tk.Label(window, image=photo)
labimg.image = photo 
labimg.pack()
###############################################
```

Comment: So I did this and got a new error as a result, _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist ... Would you also know about this? Thanks again for the help